# How can I better control the lm() estimate labels for an ordered factor?

Tags: r, lm, r-factor

I have data containing an ordered factor variable with many levels, such as this:

```
set.seed(1234)
y <- runif(100,0,100)
x <- rep_len(as.character(c(1991:2013)), length.out = 100)
df<-data.frame("x" = factor(x,ordered = TRUE), y)
```

When I use these data in `lm()`, R changes the names of estimated coefficients in a way that I think sacrifices clarity.

```
summary(lm(data = df, formula = y~x))
```

produces the following:

```
...Truncated...

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  43.8665     2.9456  14.892   <2e-16 ***
x.L           0.5284    13.9151   0.038    0.970    
x.Q         -17.6699    14.1375  -1.250    0.215    
x.C           0.3310    13.9882   0.024    0.981    
x^4          -0.8420    14.0647  -0.060    0.952    
x^5          20.1605    14.0629   1.434    0.156  

...Truncated...
```

In order to avoid this, I could "un-order" the factor but this is inconvenient to my circumstance. Is there a way to force R to use the actual level names? Also, what is the explanation of `x.L`, `x.Q` and `x.C` for the first three estimate names, only?

Comment: The default for ordered factors is to encode them with orthogonal polynomial contrasts, hence a **L**inear component, **Q**uadratic component, **C**ubic component and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from lack of answers that the best way to accomplish these goals is simply to "un-order" the factor variable, run the linear model and then "re-order" the factor variable, such as:

```
df$x <- factor(df$x, ordered = FALSE)
m <- lm(data = df, formula = y~x)
df$x <- factor(df$x, ordered = TRUE)
```